# WordPress custom public page via plugin development prevent theme CSS

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-plugin-creation

I am developing my first WordPress plugin for a simple quotation
I created settings pages at admin section those are working fine as I have not used any special css.
I have also created a public page where I have used bootstrap5 and fontawsome
but when it loads all its CSS is broken as default wordpress theme css also getting applied on it. it might be fixed for a specific theme, but is the theme is changed again it will be broken with new theme.
How can I handle this?

```
add_filter('the_content', array($this,'public_page'));

function public_page($content) {
    if(is_page()){
        $public_page_slug =  get_option("alam_calc_slug",'alam-calc');
        $current_page = sanitize_post( $GLOBALS['wp_the_query']->get_queried_object() );
        $slug = $current_page->post_name; 
        if( is_singular() && 
            is_main_query() && 
            $slug  == $public_page_slug  
        ) {  
            //this file has my custom page content including bootstrap.css.js and fontawsome
            require_once dirname(__FILE__).'\inc\index.php';
            return;
        }   
    }
    return $content;
}///end public_page()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `wp_enqueue_scripts` action hook to load the custom styles on your front end.

Usage:

```php
/**
* Load custom CSS and JavaScript.
*/
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpdocs_my_enqueue_scripts' );
function wpdocs_my_enqueue_scripts() : void {
    // Enqueue my styles.
    wp_enqueue_style( 'wpdocs-bootstrap-style', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'wpdocs-datatables-bootstrap-style', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.21/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css' );
     
    // Enqueue my scripts.
    wp_enqueue_script( 'wpdocs-bootstrap-bundle-script', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js', array(), null, true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'wpdocs-datatables-bootstrap-script', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.21/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js', array(), null, true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'wpdocs-jquery-datatables-script', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js', array(), null, true );    
}
```

Comment: Dear already used it, but along with my custom bootstrap, Wordpress theme styles are also being applied on it. I want to prevent those

Comment: Unable to understand your use case here. WordPress doesn't apply any it's style on the frontend theme, your theme does. Can you please attach related screenshots?